# Definir valor padrão para coluna do banco de dados no Laravel 4

Tags: php, sql, laravel-4

Como posso adicionar um valor default para uma coluna da minha tabela MySQL através do Laravel 4?

No SQL seria:

```
create table tabelaTeste(
    id int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    coluna1 varchar(50) DEFAULT valor,
    PRIMARY KEY(id));
```

No Laravel estou criando assim:

```
Schema::create('tabelaTeste', function ($table){
    $table->increments('id');
    $table->string('coluna1', '50');
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Faz assim, chamando o método default de forma encadeada:

```
Schema::create('tabelaTeste', function ($table){
    $table->increments('id');
    $table->string('coluna1', '50')->default('valor');
});
```